# C program can´t find header, "No such file or directory"

Tags: c

While working with C I ran into a problem with following code:

```
#include "xlsxwriter.h"
 
int main() {
 
    lxw_workbook  *workbook = workbook_new("hello_world.xlsx");
    lxw_worksheet *worksheet = workbook_add_worksheet(workbook, NULL);
 
    worksheet_write_string(worksheet, 0, 0, "Hello", NULL);
    worksheet_write_number(worksheet, 1, 0, 123, NULL);
 
    workbook_close(workbook);
 
    return 0;
}
```

This is the tasks.json file (which was automatically generated):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using VSCode.

The source code and the header file are in the same folder so I don´t really know why this doesn´t work.

My first mistake was that I included the header file with <>, which couldn´t work but now I am stuck.

Has anyone got an idea what went wrong?

Comment: The problem is with your compile configuration, not your code. Show that instead.

Comment: `#include <>` means it will check for the file in `/usr/include` and `#include ""` means it will check for the file in your local directory

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Mentioning VSCode is a good indicator that the compiler options are very likely not correct even without reading the question

Comment: How can I show you the compile configurations?

Comment: Show the content of `tasks.json`

Comment: You need to add a line `"-I <path to your xlswriter include files>"` to the `"args":[ ... ]` section of that json file. You likely also need a line `"-l<library to add>"` to tell the linker where the functions of xlswriter can be found. The documentation of that package should tell you what library you need to add.

Comment: Do I have to include the whole path like C:\\...\...\...\xlsxwriter.h or is it enough to include xlsxwriter.h?

Comment: You need to add the path to `tasks.json` and in the C file you use `#include "xlsxwriter.h"`

Comment: The [documentation](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/getting_started.html#gsg_using) tells us: "In some OS environments, or if you changed the PREFIX location, you may have to provide explicit include and lib paths: cc myexcel.c -o myexcel -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lxlsxwriter"

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to let the compiler know where the header file is.

In command line, with gcc (or g++), if your header is in C:\devtools\inc, it should like something like this :

> g++ main.cpp -o test.exe -I/C/devtools/inc

Next, you will certainly have to add the lib (.dll?) file, adding -L for the directory and -l for the reduced filename...

Hopefully you are using an IDE, going to the project properties usually allows for stuff like (in Netbeans) "Include Directories and Headers" for compiling, and "Additional Library Directories", and/or "Libraries" for linking. The generated makefile will thus have all it needs!

Comment: "Hopefully you are using an IDE" The OP is using VSCode.

Comment: I see it now : Maybe missed the info, maybe an edit; who knows...
Adding compile options somehow seems like the solution anyways don't you think @Gerhardh?

Comment: Thank you very much but suppose I personally have to a little bit before that because I don´t understand very much of that? What exactly is the command line? I am using windows if this matters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65133723/1747773
explains how to add include (header) paths.

Comment: Yes, adding the correct options is the solution. Unfortunately you don't tell how to do that. Also the linked answer does not tell it. It just mentions "For an optimized experience, don't forget to also set up the path to the compiler" without the most important part how to do it.

Comment: Well it starts with "Open the Command Palette (F1 or Ctrl+Shift+P), look for "C/C++: Edit configurations (UI)", and add the desired folders under "Include path"."
and links to CS lecture notes for VSCode based C/C++ development, where §1.2 explains how to customize a project... If you really think that's not enough, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: The "include path" setting mentioned is only used for Intellisense. It doesn't help with compiling. Instead of a comment holding a link o an answer where a link to some lectures can be found, the information of that link would be the answer.